# Unit tests in Android Studio 0.8

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

> **BREAKING NEWS:** Android Studio 1.1.0 now has built-in support for unit testing. See more here: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

> At first I know that there are very, very, *very* much similar questions (even here on SO). Most of them are terribly outdated so I'm asking a fresh new question which should be up to date for Android Studio 0.8.x.

I know there are some libraries which work somehow, but in almost each case I had no evidence that the information were up to date. I know there is e.g. [roboelectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric), there are also some deprecated Jake Wharton like [gradle-android-test-plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin) or [double-espresso](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso), I also found the library [RoboSpock](https://github.com/Polidea/RoboSpock) and [Deckard](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle). But none of them seems to have any Android Studio integration.

After long reseach I found this two bugs in all implementations:

- The classpath is broken and needs to been hacked to get junit running
- The junit tests cannot been debugged

What I'm looking for:

- I want to automatically test an algorithm (which is plain java)
- I want to check the integration in my Android app works
- I want an integration in Android Studio so that I can jump into the code out of a stacktrace
- I want to step thrue the test code

I found also somewhere a nice hack which run the tests in gradle as an external task and pushed the results into AS so that the results could been displayed, but unfortunately I cannot find that link again (and if I remember correctly it did also not work for me).

Do you guys have some fresh references? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the .iml file that Android Studio generates to point to your test-classes directory and also to fix the Stub error from Junit. There is currently no work around for this.

[Gradlectric](https://github.com/marcoRS/gradlectric) is a sample that uses the [Robolectric Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin) to run unit tests in Android Studio.

Comment: I tried to implement it like in your project however I always end in a *Class not found: "com.example.test.FirstTest"* error.

Comment: Well I used [this fix](https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template/wiki/Tests-in-Android-Studio---IntellJ) now it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I updated my repo to include the missing step.

Answer (score 1):

Here you miss one example project setup https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template

> But none of them seems to have any Android Studio integration.

This project is maintained for android studio

> The classpath is broken and needs to been hacked to get junit running

gradle scripts will fix the classpath

> The junit tests cannot been debugged

tests a running inside AS so they are easy to debug

Comment: I used the accepted answer mixed with your answer. However I can just accept one answer so you got a +1.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/tree/dev/lib-manipulation) project of mine does not cover *all* your requests, but a fair lot of them.
It covers a default Java test case, and some tests interacting with Views.

The root project uses Travis CI, which uses `gradle connectedCheck` to run the tests. To be able to debug the tests, you can just create a test run configuration in AS and run it in debugging mode.

Note that this does not use any special Android testing frameworks like robolectric.

Comment: It's hard to understand that project gradle files since you are referencing files which seems not to be in the version control. Where does the results appear (in case of an error) just as a html/xml file in the build directory or where?

Comment: Everything is in the version control. You might have to navigate to the root, as the entire project is made of multiple modules. This module has some tests in it. The gradle files used by `apply from: ...` do not have anything to do with the unit tests.
Using the gradle command, results will appear as html/xml indeed, when running test configuration in AS, you will get nice output in the AS GUI.

Comment: I'll need to check that. I will leave another comment when I'm done. (That could take some time I'm fixing right now something else)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a fork of Jake Wharton's  gradle-android-test-plugin  [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin). This is compatible with AS 0.6 and is regularly maintained by Robolectric. You can look at [this project](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-maven) to set up Robolectric in Android Studio with help of this plugin. You can achieve fair bit of functionality you mentioned with the help of robolectric-gradle-plugin. You can also successfully debug your test code using AS.

Comment: Well I have a big problem with Deckard (projects) I want to extend a existing project. That is not explained at all on their pages. My problem with that maven plugin is that I have maven not installed even that `brew` which I never heard. Can you enlighten me in that points?

Comment: What operating system you are using ? Also the procedure is quite similar for a new or existing project as long as you are using a Android Studio Project. Follow the instructions given here - https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin