# Unit testing Cloud Datastore with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, google-app-engine, android-studio

I am trying to write unit tests for a Cloud Endpoints backend, specifically using Datastore.  (Unit testing without access to any specific Android modules is working as expected.)

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229537/how-to-unit-test-google-cloud-endpoints-java-using-android-studio-0-8), I added the following to my backend's build.gradle:

```
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.8'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.8'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.8'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12+'
```

My code is minimized from [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting) and located at `backend/src/test/java/<package>`:

```
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

public class ExampleDatastoreTest {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper datastoreHelper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    @org.junit.Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        datastoreHelper.setUp();
    }

    @org.junit.After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        datastoreHelper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testExample() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError` when I call `tearDown` on my `LocalServiceTestHelper`.

Per [that tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting), I still need to include:

```
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar
${SDK_ROOT}/lib/impl/appengine-tools-sdk.jar
```

Using File > Project Structure in Android Studio 1.2.2, I found these options:

```
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.9.25'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.25'
testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:1.9.25'
```

The `appengine-tools-sdk` looks good, but I don't seem to be able to find `appengine-api`.  The two I listed above are the closest I found.  I continue to get the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Same here, I use eclipse plug-in for java. can not find appengine-tools-sdk.jar.